# Find All Tables in a SQL query with a Python Script

Tags: python

Another way to say this is "find all substrings within a string"; while there's a bunch of these posts on stackoverflow already, none I've found quite get the job done.

```
#query variable
query = "select * from table1 a join table2 b on a.id = b.id left join table3 c on b.id = c.id where x = 5;"
query_list = query.split()

#find the adjacent word in a list
def find_adjacents(some_value, some_list):
    i = some_list.index(some_value)
    return some_list[i:i+2]

print('from tables:', find_adjacents("from", query_list)[1])
print('join tables:', find_adjacents("join", query_list)[1])

>>>from tables: table1
>>>join tables: table2
```

There should be one more `join tables: table3`. How do I get this to print All instances of the adjacent substring "join"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you're after?

```
# Query variable
query = "select * from table1 a join table2 b on a.id = b.id left join table3 c on b.id = c.id where x = 5;"
query_list = query.split()

def find_adjacents(some_value, some_list):
    val = [index for index, value in enumerate(some_list) if value == some_value]

    allVal = []
    for x in val:
        allVal.append(some_list[x+1])
    return allVal

>>> print('from tables:', find_adjacents("from", query_list))
from tables: ['table1']

>>> print('join tables:', find_adjacents("join", query_list))
join tables: ['table2', 'table3']
```

Comment: Yes sir brother (or woman!) - that's exactly what i was looking for. thank you